# TypeError: update_info() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given) - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo

Since I'm migrating some v7 modules into v10 community, I'm still facing some errors, and challenges, for example, this is a wizard which looks for vats:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class UpdateInfoPartner(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'update.info.partner'

def update_info(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    context = context or {} #dict(self._context or {})
    seniat_url_obj = self.pool.get('seniat.url')
    self.env.cr.execute('''SELECT id FROM res_partner WHERE vat ilike 'VE%';''')
    record = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    pids = [item[0] for item in record]
    seniat_url_obj.connect_seniat(self.env.cr, uid, pids, context=context,
                                  all_rif=True)
    return{}
```

But every time I try to run this method it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: update_info() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Had this kind of error before on python, but I cannot see it well on this method.

Any ideas?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this can help you:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class UpdateInfoPartner(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'update.info.partner'

def update_info(self):

    context = dict(self.env.context or {})
    seniat_url_obj = self.env['seniat.url']
    self.env.cr.execute('''SELECT id FROM res_partner WHERE vat ilike 'VE%';''')
    record = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    pids = [item[0] for item in record]
    seniat_url_obj.connect_seniat(self.env.cr, self.env.uid, pids,context=self.env.context, all_rif=True)
    return{}
```